# Как из подзапроса достать поле.

Tags: access, sql

Как из второго подзапроса вытащить поле РодителиДети.КодРебенка

```
SELECT Фамилия, Имя FROM Ребенок
WHERE Ребенок.КодРебенка IN (SELECT РодителиДети.КодРебенка as codeReb, count(РодителиДети.КодРодителя)
FROM РодителиДети
GROUP BY РодителиДети.КодРебенка
HAVING count(РодителиДети.КодРодителя)=1).codeReb;
```

Пробовал так:

```
SELECT Фамилия, Имя FROM Ребенок
WHERE Ребенок.КодРебенка IN (SELECT РодителиДети.КодРебенка as codeReb, count(РодителиДети.КодРодителя)
FROM РодителиДети
GROUP BY РодителиДети.КодРебенка
HAVING count(РодителиДети.КодРодителя)=1).codeReb;
```

но так не работает.

UPD: 
Сделал так

```
SELECT Фамилия, Имя 
FROM Ребенок
WHERE Ребенок.КодРебенка IN (
    SELECT X.BAG 
    FROM (
        SELECT РодителиДети.КодРебенка As BAG, count(РодителиДети.КодРодителя)
        FROM РодителиДети
        GROUP BY РодителиДети.КодРебенка
        HAVING count(РодителиДети.КодРодителя)=1
    ) 
    As X
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лишние операции, на мой взгляд:

```
SELECT Фамилия, Имя FROM Ребенок
WHERE Ребенок.КодРебенка IN (SELECT РодителиДети.КодРебенка
FROM РодителиДети
GROUP BY РодителиДети.КодРебенка
HAVING count(РодителиДети.КодРодителя)=1);
```

Comment: странно.. до этого у меня так не работало, а сейчас работает) 
Ведь having работает по сгруппированной таблице и говорит что поля "count(РодителиДети.КодРодителя)" не существует и т.д.

Comment: Ну, так вам есть с чем сравнить. А мне нечего ответить без запроса.